TypeScript array access with noUncheckedIndexedAccess
I'm trying to figure out why TypeScript allows array access in the first case below but not the second. I have noUncheckedIndexedAccess enabled, but I'm checking that the accessed objects are not undefined before accessing them.
This doesn't error:
const arr: number[][] = [[], [], []];
if (arr[0] != undefined) {  
    arr[0][0] = 42;  
}

But this does:
function twoDimArrayAccess(arr: number[][], x: number, y: number) {
    if (arr[x] != undefined) {
        arr[x][y] = 1;
        ^^^^^^ 
        // TS2532: Object is possibly undefined

    }
}


Your code will actually work as-is starting with TS5.5, which introduces control flow narrowing for constant indexed accesses. If you can't upgrade then you need to refactor as shown in this playground link to work around ms/TS#56389. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz great to know, thanks! This might circumvent the issue entirely. The answer below does go into detail about constant indexed access, so I do feel like it's an adequate answer. However I think this information is very helpful as an aside.

Can you explain how it's an aside? It seems to directly be about your issue. The answer below doesn't talk about x being a variable at all, and that's really the whole issue. I'm inclined to actually write up an answer here since the one below doesn't get to what I think of as the crux of the matter. But of course I don't expect you to accept or even upvote my answer if I do that.

TL; DR: Your code will work as-is in TypeScript 5.5 and above due to control flow narrowing for constant indexed accesses as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#57847.

TypeScript has long supported narrowing on dotted property indexed accesses, like
const val: { a?: { b: string } | undefined } = { a: { b: "" } };
if (val.a) {
    val.a.b = "x"
}

But for bracket property indexed access like
const arr: ({ b: string } | undefined)[] = [{ b: "" }];
if (arr[0] != undefined) {
    arr[0].b = "x"
}  

originally it didn't work. So microsoft/TypeScript#10530 was opened. Soon some bracket indexed narrowing was supported, such as the above check, where the key being indexed is of a literal type like 0.
But when the key being indexed was a variable and only known to be a wide type like number, it still wasn't supported:
function f(arr: ({ b: string } | undefined)[], x: number) {
    if (arr[x] != undefined) {
        arr[x].b = "x"; // error! TS5.4 and below
    }
}

That's because the identity of the key wasn't tracked, just its type.  So checking arr[x] and then writing arr[x].b = "x" was not considered safe because checking arr[x] and then writing arr[x2].b = "x" is not safe if x2 and x are both numbers.

This limitation was present for a long time.  The standard workaround people used for microsoft/TypeScript#10530 was to save the indexed access to its own variable, and then do narrowing on that variable:
function f(arr: ({ b: string } | undefined)[], x: number) {
    const arrX = arr[x];
    if (arrX != undefined) {
        arrX.b = "x"; // okay
    }
}

If you're stuck on TypeScript 5.4 or below, you should use that approach or something like it.

Eventually microsoft/TypeScript#10530 was closed since many use cases were supported and microsoft/TypeScript#56389 was opened to capture this remaining issue with a variable key. And microsoft/TypeScript#57847 was implemented to fix it. When indexing into an object obj with key key, narrowing should now happen on obj[key] as long as neither obj nor key are mutated.  This will be released with TypeScript 5.5, after which the problem will just go away by itself:
function f(arr: ({ b: string } | undefined)[], x: number) {
    if (arr[x] != undefined) {
        arr[x].b = "x"; // okay, TS 5.5 and above
    }
}

If you can upgrade to TypeScript 5.5, you should do so.
Playground link to code

When you set noUncheckedIndexedAccess to true, Typescript assumes that it is always possible for your array access to go out of bounds. Therefore your array type will be recognized as:
((number | undefined)[] | undefined)[]

When access arr[x], it returns a value that may be undefined (xxx | undefined). Because of the complexity of tracking element changes in arrays, Typescript can't conclude whether the arr array has changed or not between if (arr[x]) and actually accessing arr[x]. So in general it cannot conclude that arr[x] is not undefined.
If you pass in a constant or a literal value like arr[0], Typescript currently assumes that this value will not change after if (arr[0]), which in fact isn't entirely true. For example, the following code will not report an error at compile time, but it will throw an error at runtime:
const arr: number[][] = [[], [], []];
if (arr[0]) {
  arr.length = 0;   
  arr[0][0] = 42; // Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0') 
}

Whether Typescript asserts undefined or not, it's not really perfect. So it takes a more compromise estimate, hence the current behavior.
If you're sure that your array accesses won't go out of bounds, you can use ! (arr[x]![y]) to bypass compile-time linting.
